# How to show image when all sprites are collected p5js (play)

Tags: javascript, p5.js, collect

I'm coding a simple game in p5js with the play library in which a person wins after collecting all the "sprinkles". But I can't figure out how to show an image when all the sprinkles are collected. Can someone please help me out? I put the code parts in which the "sprinkles" and collect things happen because the total code is quite long.

```
function setup(){
    sprinkles = new Group();

    for(var i = 0; i <25; i++) {
      var ang = random(360);
      var px = SCENE_W/2 + 1000*cos(radians(ang));
      var py = SCENE_H/2 + 1000*sin(radians(ang));
      createSprinkles(2, px, py);
    }
}

 function draw(){
    for(var j=0; j<sprinkles.length; j++) {
      var s = sprinkles[j];
      if(s.position.x<-MARGIN) s.position.x = SCENE_W+MARGIN;
      if(s.position.x>SCENE_W+MARGIN) s.position.x = -MARGIN;
      if(s.position.y<-MARGIN) s.position.y = SCENE_H+MARGIN;
      if(s.position.y>SCENE_H+MARGIN) s.position.y = -MARGIN;
    }
  mouse.overlap(sprinkles, collect);
} 

function createSprinkles(type, x, y){
    var a = createSprite(x, y);
    var img = loadImage('assets/sprinkles/sprinkle'+floor(random(0,5))+'.png');
    a.addImage(img);
    a.setSpeed(2.5-(type/2), random(360));
    a.rotationSpeed = 0.5;
    sprinkles.add(a);
  }

  function collect(collector, collected) {
    collector.changeAnimation('stretch');
    collector.animation.rewind();
    collected.remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it! I made a really dumb mistake... the dumbest one ever because I'm too tired. yay.

So if anyone is wondering about the same thing:

```
if(sprinkles.length<1){
   background(255,200,0);
}
```

Here I tried a simple thing with the background colour to see if it works. Just add this code in the function draw(){} part and you're done!